# Does Stack Exchange remember the last edit summary I wrote for a post?

Tags: support, edits, edit-summary

Does Stack Exchange remember what I used as edit summary last time I edited a post?

I noticed that the edit summary was already set when I edited a post; I expanded the description, and clicked on the "Save Edits" button. I thought I was editing it during the grace period, but it was not so.

[image: screenshot]

I don't find any post that reports the way the edit summary is handled has been changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you *begin* editing during the grace period, the previous edit summary will be filled in.

If you're then a bit slow to submit your edit and the grace period expires, a new revision will be created.

Comment: Oh, so "deleted 59 characters" when I haven't even deleted anything yet means I am still "revising the revision". No wonder!